# Bootstrap .form-inline but keep label above fields

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label for="id_first_name">First Name</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
            <input class="form-control" id="id_first_name" name="first_name" type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label for="id_last_name">Last Name</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
            <input class="form-control" id="id_last_name" name="last_name" type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I get a output similar to this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKvOY.png
But I want the labels above the fields.

I googled and I see a lot of people have the same problem but exactly the opposite. They have the labels above the fields and want them in the same line. However I tried their code, still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I've created [this](https://jsfiddle.net/jonqf7vr/1/) fiddle demonstrating this using what you provided.  `form-group` should do the trick.

Comment: Are you sure you are including Bootstrap 3 in your application properly?